# Declare conformance to C# interface for class I don't own

Tags: c#, interface

Let's say I'm working with multiple classes in a third party library, all of which contain an `int ID {get;}` property. For example:

```
class A {
    ...
    int ID {get;}
    ...
}

class B {
    ...
    int ID {get;}
    ...
}
```

`ID` is the only property I need to use in a method I'm writing, which needs a reference to either A or B. I've declared an interface:

```
interface IHasID
{
    int ID {get;}
}
```

But I can't treat either `A` or `B` as `IHasID` when calling my method.

In Swift, for instance, I could declare an extension with conformance to an "protocol" (Swift's version of interfaces). I don't see a way to do that with C#. What's the closest way to refer to unrelated classes that share a property?

Comment: Why not just make overloads of your method?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind would be to create a wrapper class around `A` and `B` that ats like an adapter to `IHasID`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way of doing that at the moment. You could:

- Just use dynamic typing and use `ID` that way with no type-checking at compile-time
- Wrap each library class in your own class that *does* implement an interface
- Ask the maintainers to add an interface

It's *possible* that this feature will be added to C# at some time. See Mads Torgersen's [issue about shapes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164) for details - but I suspect it's a long way off.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of wrapping the classes, you *could* use a generic method along with a selector for the ID. The usage here is trivial, but the pattern is useful in some cases.

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T value, Func<T, int> selectId)
{
    var id = selectId(value);
}
```

and

```
MyMethod<A>(a, value => value.ID);
MyMethod<B>(b, value => value.ID);
```

which can be shorted to

```
MyMethod(a, value => value.ID);
MyMethod(b, value => value.ID);
```

Note that even though they look the same, the two lambdas are not identical.

`Func<A, int>` vs `Func<B, int>`

Comment: You could even have a class with a method per type, and use method group conversions, letting type inference handle it: `Foo(new A(), IdExtractor.ExtractId); Foo(new B(), IdExtractor.ExtractId);`

Comment: Can you expand on your comment? I'm not sure what type `ExtractId` is.

Comment: It would be an overloaded set of methods in the `IdExtractor` class, e.g. `public int ExtractId(A a) { ... } public int ExtractId(B b) { ... }` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make a generic wrapper class that has all of the following:

- An implementation of `IHasID` interface,
- A constructor that takes `T` and `Func<T,int>` to get the ID, and
- A getter for the wrapped value.

Here is an example:

```
class HasId<T> : IHasId {
    private readonly Func<T,int> idGetter;
    public Value {get;}
    public Id => idGetter(Value);
    public HasId(T val, Func<T,int> idGetter) {
        Value = value;
        this.idGetter = idGetter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (not so optimal) solution is use reflection:

```
static int IdOf<T>(T t)
{
    return (int)typeof(T).GetProperty("ID").GetValue(t);
}
```

I don't really like this solution, but I included it anyway because it's an option...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the way of writing an adapter as a solution, this is my typical implementation for joining types into a hierarchy.

```
public abstract class HasIDAdapter : IHasID {
    public abstract int ID {get;}

    private class AAdapter : HasIDAdapter {
        A _a;
        public AAdapter(A a) {
            _a = a;
        }

        public override int ID { get => _a.ID; }
    }

    private class BAdapter : HasIDAdapter {
        B _b;
        public BAdapter(B b) {
            _b = b;
        }

        public override int ID {get => _b.ID;}
    }

    public static implicit operator HasIDAdapter(A a) => new AAdapter(a);
    public static implicit operator HasIDAdapter(B b) => new BAdapter(b);
}
```

This sort of pushes the problem though, you still need to convert from `A` or `B` to `HasIDAdapter` before you can utilize the interface, but this can be done by way of taking `HasIDAdapter` as a method parameter, or by assigning your `A` or `B` instance to a variable of the `HasIDAdapter` type before passing it to a `IHasID` method.